# indicate which users are currently logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to find a way to display logged in active users on my web app.  I'm not using any gem for authentication like Devise.  I have a list of users and wanted to show an icon or some type of indicator next to a users name if they are currently on the site.

I'm not sure how to go about this.  Possibly I could add a column called `currently_logged_in` to my `User` model and could set the value to `true` when the session is created and then to `false` when the user session is destroyed?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
      if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id #session id created off of the 
        redirect_to(session[:intended_url] || user)
        session[:intended_url] = nil #removes url from the sessions 
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
        render :new
      end
    end

    def destroy
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to root_url
    end

end
```

User model

```
 # tries to find an existing user in the database so that they can be authenticated.
  def self.authenticate(email, password)
      user = User.find_by(email: email) # returns user or nil value
      user && user.authenticate(password) # if user exists validate that password is correct
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "currently on the site".

Adding a `currently_logged_in` column like you described works IF you want to mark users that are currently logged in. However most users don't log out when leaving a website these days so that probably won't do what you want.

A better solution would be to add a `last_active_at` column which you can update with the current time whenever a user performs some action. Then determine a threshold that makes sense for your website, let's say 15 minutes, and only mark users in your list that have a `last_active_at` value less than 15 minutes in the past.

Assuming the definition of "active user" for your website involves hitting authenticated endpoints it would be as simple as changing your authenticate method to:

```
def self.authenticate(email, password)
  user = User.find_by(email: email) # returns user or nil value
  if user && user.authenticate(password)
    user.update!(last_active_at: Time.now)     
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach.  I could update the last_active_at column when a user performs a search, creates a post, etc... Do you think there would be a negative performance impact if I were to implement this?  Just wondering how constantly updating that column for all users when they perform actions will work out performance wise?

Comment: I doubt it will impact performance that much. The major consideration is how often will a post creation/ search happen per user. If it is more than once a second per user this method *might* starting to bottleneck, but I bet posts and searches happen far less frequently than that

Comment: If performance does become and issue for whatever reason, the next best bet would be to implement a heartbeat using web sockets that hits an endpoint to update `last_active_at`. This will be more complicated and I would recommend using the simple solution until it becomes a problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You need to find current user on site.
You may b call `current_user` method which is in application helper and you should display all current user in wherever you want.
For Example,

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def current_user
  @current_user ||= session[:user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
 end
end
```

And you call this method in Session controller as `@current_user`.